# How to show specific image in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I had downloaded for this code,it is working but When i am clicking the specific image that time it is not working,i dont know what will do...

```
<div class="img-box">
        <ul>
            <?php 
             $query1="SELECT * FROM user_photos_offline";
             $sql=mysql_query($query1); 
             $results=array();
             while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            ?>
            <li>
            <img src="images/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image']?>"/>
                <div class="mask"><div class="mag"><div class="plus"></div></div></div>    
            </li>
             <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div> 
 <div class="full-screen-mask">
    <div class="view-port">
        <div class="pre">
            <span>-</span>
        </div>
        <div class="pic"><img /></div>
        <div class="next">
            <span>+</span>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="close">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
$(".img-box ul li").click(function(){
 var index = $(this).index();
num = index+1;
$(".pic img").attr("src","images/pic-"+num+".png") });//hear i want show the onclick specific image
```

Comment: what is not working. Please elaborate..!

Comment: When i am clicking one specific image i want show that image on here $(".pic img") .attr("src","images/photoname.png")

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
$(".img-box ul li").click(function()
{
var img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
$(".pic img").attr("src",img) });//hear i want show the onclick specific image
</script>
```

Comment: I am getting like this images/images/cropped-images/5624ca2dc9778.png  I want like this images/cropped-images/5624ca2dc9778.png ,remove images folder